# Do a loop with multiple constant condition VBA

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I am trying to do a loop but I'm a little stuck.

```
Sub Macro()

Range("A392: A401").Value = Range("N2")

Range("A402: A411").Value = Range("N3")

Range("A412: A421").Value = Range("N4")

Range("A422: A431").Value = Range("N5")

....
```

I need to repeat this logic ( On column A to set a value for each 10 rows) this value will be from Column N from 1 to 1 until it finds an empty row ...

I'm not being able to do the loop with these multiples conditions, would you please help me ?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is your intention to repeat each non-empty cell value found in column `N` 10 times, starting from the fixed top cell `A392`?

Answer (score 1):

[Range.Offset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.offset) is a great method to manipulate ranges. Using it, we can automate the ranges to move down the sheet with each loop.

```vb
Sub Macro()
    Dim i As Long
    While Range("N2").Offset(i) <> ""
        'Offset will shift N2 down by one each loop
        'Offset will shift the 10 cell range down by 10 on each loop
        Range("A392: A401").Offset(i * 10).Value = Range("N2").Offset(i)
        i = i + 1
    Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: Small & understandable code. Upvoted as block copying can be a helpful method which is neglected sometimes :+) - You might be interested in my answer, too.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what's your actual intention:

- 1. Repeat all values in column `N2:N5` 10 times and append the whole data block to the first free cell in column A.
- 2. Repeat all non-empty values in column N 10 times and write them to a fixed target starting with cell `A392`.

In both cases you can prefill an **array** and write it to the defined target in column A. Looping through an array has some speed advantages whereas looping through a *range* by means of VBA can be time consuming.

*The direct (untested) copying of whole blocks as shown by *@Toddleson* can improve this behaviour, depending on total range sizes.*

**Case 1**

```
Sub Example1()
    Const RowsCount As Long = 10
    With Sheet1                            ' << change to your project's sheet (Code)Name
        'get values to repeat & count them
        Dim vals: vals = .Range("N2:N5")
        Dim cnt As Long: cnt = UBound(vals)
        'provide for 1-based 2-dim results array
        Dim results
        ReDim results(1 To RowsCount * cnt, 1 To 1)
        'fill array with repeated values
        Dim i As Long, j As Long
        For i = 1 To cnt
            For j = 1 To RowsCount
                results((i - 1) * RowsCount + j, 1) = vals(i, 1)
            Next j
        Next i
        'append above data block
        Dim nxtRow As Long
        nxtRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        .Range("A" & nxtRow).Resize(UBound(results), 1) = results
    End With
End Sub
```

**Case 2**

```
Sub Example2()
    Const RowsCount As Long = 10
    With Sheet1               ' << change to your project's sheet (Code)Name
        'get values to repeat & count them
        Dim lastRow As Long
        lastRow = .Range("N" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Dim vals: vals = .Range("N2:N" & lastRow)
        Dim ValsCount As Long: ValsCount = UBound(vals)
        'provide for 1-based 2-dim results array
        Dim results
        ReDim results(1 To RowsCount * ValsCount, 1 To 1)
        'fill array with repeated values
        Dim i As Long, j As Long, ii As Long
        For i = 1 To ValsCount
            If Len(vals(i, 1)) > 0 Then     ' check if non-empty value in column N
                ii = ii + 1
                For j = 1 To RowsCount
                    results((ii - 1) * RowsCount + j, 1) = vals(i, 1)
                Next j
            End If
        Next i
        'write data block to fixed target starting with A392
        .Range("A392").Resize(UBound(results), 1) = results
    End With
End Sub
```